# Python recursive return

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I'm doing a method to check if a Binary Search Tree(BST) is a Red-Black Tree

```
def isRedBlack(tree,index):
        if(tree[0][1]=='red'):
            return False
        elif(tree[index][0]=='EMPTY' and tree[index][1]=='red'):
            return False
        elif(tree[index][1]=='red'):
            if(tree[2*index+1][1]!='black' or tree[2*index+2][1]!='black'):
                print("PROBLEM HERE")
                return False
        else:            
            if(2*index+1<len(tree)):
                isRedBlack(tree,2*index+1)
            if(2*index+2<len(tree)):
                isRedBlack(tree,2*index+2)
            return True

redBlack = [(3,'black'),(8,'red'),(8,'red'),('EMPTY','black'),('EMPTY','black'),('EMPTY','black'),('EMPTY','red')]

print("IS READBLACK: ",isRedBlack(redBlack,0))
```

The problem is that the code enters the condition when its red but one of its childrens isnt black, so it should return False, but instead of returning False it continues recursing until the end and returns True.

Comment: you need to `return isRedBlack(tree,2*index+1)` and `return isRedBlack(tree,2*index+2)`

Comment: I previously tried that and it returns None

Comment: Yes it does, when the root of the tree is black it passes and enters that elif, I'm running it right now, and it enters the if condition inside the elif, and prints the "PROBLEM HERE" but for some reason the False is not being returned, instead it returns whatever I place at the end of the else

Comment: because you're not `return`-ing your calls, and there is an issue with your logic. Set it up with the returns, and you'll see that when `index=1` we enter the `elif(tree[index][1]=='red')`, but return `None` because `(tree[2*index+1][1]!='black' or tree[2*index+2][1]!='black')` is untrue.

Comment: @DanielRodríguez Sorry i was wrong. I was trying test cases of my own and it was't reflecting.

Comment: @asongtoruin You are correct, I added an else return True and the code works, post it as a solution to mark it.

Comment: @JkShaw its ok man, thanks for your help